# Find points in specific range with various obstacles between

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a 2-D char array/vector where I have either a clear cell (`.`), cell with an obstacle (`#`) or a cell with a communication tower(`T`) in a certain number of lines and columns.

Given that you can only "walk" top, right, bottom or left (no diagonals), that you cannot cross the obstacles' cells and that the towers are number from top-left to bottom-right and have a range D, how can I find which towers are in range of each others?

Example:
2-D Vector with towers with defined range of 3 cells each one.

`.#...
T#.T.
.#...
T...T
.....`

Tower 1 and Tower 3 are both in range of each other.

Tower 2 and Tower 4 are both in range of each other.

Tower 2 is not in range of Tower 1 because there is an obstacle.

Comment: Model as a directed graph with one vertex per cell, and run DFS from each tower.

Comment: BTW, according to your description, only "obstacles" block paths, meaning towers themselves do not block paths, meaning tower 2 *is* reachable from tower 1 (guessing your tower numbering).

Comment: If the towers have enough range then yes tower 2 is reachable from tower 1, which does not happen in the example.

Comment: Ah, I missed the range limit.